# Accessing detached .mdf database over TCP/IP

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, ms-access-2003, isolation-level

My problem is exactly as described in title, but I am not familiar with MS Access, and I'd like to avoid interacting with it at any cost.
I have stumbled upon a point of sale (POS) system, which is built on MS Access. MSAccess Runtime 2003, to be specific. It uses a couple of .mdf files, which reside in a shared folder on the same network, and there are, at the moment, 2 POS computers, working with the same database simultaneously. SQL Server 2008 Express instance is running on server, but it only lists the default databases. Here's part of POS config, running on server machine:

```
DBConnString=DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=(local);APP=Microsoft® Access;UID=sa;PWD=;DATABASE=DB_name
Systemfolder=C:\Kasse
```

Systemfolder here is where the .mdf files are stored. On client PCs, it is a path to folder, shared by server.
There is also a management program, which, when set up as client, is launched like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\MSACCESS.EXE" c:\kasse\Kontor\TSKontor.mdb /Runtime /WrkGrp c:\kasse\Kontor\SYSKONTOR.MDW
```

It also has the same connection string as named before.

None of this is locking out other clients.

When I attach said MDF file to server in SSMS, I can use the database as intended, but POS program sometimes complains about locked files. I have detached them, and POS is now working as it did before.

Can someone suggest, how I can attach this database to SQL Server, without locking .mdf files? Is attaching the only solution?

Comment: Are you modifying or just reading records?

Comment: I'd want to update existing records and add new ones, yes. I actually want to set up portable barcode scanner software (TracerPlus Server), which will modify records in POS database via ODBC.